# Question about notation involving HOD

Tags: set-theory, inner-models

This is a rather naive question about notation. From the sources I have been able to find I have difficulty working out the difference between $HOD_{x}$ and $HOD[x]$ (because I cannot actually find any place where the notation $HOD_{x}$ is defined). If anyone could possibly be kind enough to explain the distinction to me.

Comment: God, I hate the HOD notations so much.

Comment: A set is $\text{OD}_x$ if it is definable over $V$ from ordinal parameters and the parameter $x$. Then $\text{HOD}_x$ consists of all sets hereditarily ordinal definable from the parameter $x$; this is an inner model of ZFC. On the other hand, $\text{HOD}[x]$ denotes the smallest inner model of ZFC containing $\text{HOD}\cup \{x\}$. So $\text{HOD}[x]\subseteq \text{HOD}_x$, but this may be a proper inclusion.

Comment: Quite confusingly, $HOD_x$ is also used to denote all sets hereditarily definable from parametes in $Ord\cup x$ (which may or may not be different than the classes in Gabe's comment).